# How to convert one element in XML to Json Array when only one element exists in xml

Tags: java, arrays, json, xml, xml-to-json

I'm trying to convert XML to JSON using the org.JSON library. However, when there is only one element in XML, it's unable to convert the element as an Array.

source.xml

```
<users>
    <user>user1</user>
</users>
```

Code for conversion:

```
File xml= new File("src/main/resources/xml/source.xml");

String data = FileUtils.readFileToString(xmlFile, "UTF-8");

String value = XML.toJSONObject(data).toString();
```

Output:

```
{
    "users": {
        "user": "user1"
    }
}
```

I tried with multiple options,

like

```
  <users>
        <?xml-multiple?>
        <user>user1</user>
    </users>
```

Output:

```
 {"users":{"user":"user1"}}
```

and with json:Array='true'

```
<users>
    <user json:Array='true'>user1</user>
</users>
```

Output:

```
  {"users":{"user":{"json:Array":true,"content":"user1"}}}
```

and nothing seems to be working. I've tried with fasterxml and unxml libraries as well.

Expected output:

```
{
    "users": {
        "user": ["user1"]
    }
}
```

Is there any library or a way to do this in Java?

Comment: Are you sure that it is that you want? Because the expected output you waiting means there can be a user with different usernames like user1,user2 etc. It will be the names for the only one user itself.

Comment: Yes, I need it in the format specified in question. I have given a sample format to explain the problem, but the object properties are different. Please let me know if you need any further clarification on the question.

Comment: You need to have a `Users` class and `user` field in it. That `user` field should be declared as `array`. Then you need to deserialize xml to that `Users` object. After that when you serialize that object to JSON it will work as you wanted